# Lee los valores, sin embargo no llena el arreglo con mis valores random. C

Tags: array, c, bucle-for, random, array-bidimensional

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  void leer(int *x,int *y);
  void llenar(int arreglo[a][b],int x,int y);
  int main(){
      int x,y,arreglo[a][b];
      leer(&x,&y);
      llenar(arreglo[a][b],x,y);
  }
  void leer(int *x,int *y){
  printf("Dame el valor de x del arreglo \n");
  scanf("%d",&*x);
  printf("Dame el valor de y del arreglo \n");
  scanf("%d",&*y);
  }
  void llenar(int arreglo[a][b],int x,int y){
      int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){
   for(j=0;j<y;j++){
    arreglo[i][j]=rand()%9+0;
    printf(" %d ",arreglo[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
  }
```

´´El codigo no parece dar los random, sin embargo si lee los valores que el usuario ingresa, pero no parece entrar al ciclo para empezar.
Repetire esto para que el bot me permita publicar:El codigo no parece dar los random, sin embargo si lee los valores que el usuario ingresa, pero no parece entrar al ciclo para empezar. El codigo no parece dar los random, sin embargo si lee los valores que el usuario ingresa, pero no parece entrar al ciclo para empezar. El codigo no parece dar los random, sin embargo si lee los valores que el usuario ingresa, pero no parece entrar al ciclo para empezar. ''

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define a 500
#define b 500
int main(){
int arreglo[a][b],x,y;
leer(&x,&y);
llenar(arreglo,x,y);
}

void leer(int *x,int *y){
printf("Valor de x \n");
scanf("%d",&*x);
printf("Valor de y \n");
scanf("%d",&*y);
}
void llenar(int arreglo[a][b],int x,int y){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(j=0;j<y;j++){
    arreglo[i][j]=rand()%9+0;
    printf(" %d ",arreglo[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Solución: en la parte de llenar en el main al momento de declarar que la función leerá el arreglo, es solo el nombre, es decir no es arreglo[a][b].